# Constructing json response. NodeJS send empty response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, httpresponse

I have this code where I want to send a response containing data that I get by requesting the database multiple times. I don't understand why it sends an empty response.

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
database = require('../database');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){

  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});

    var ttt;
    var yyy;

    database.getTagType().then(function(data) {
        ttt = "pfff";
    });

    database.getSpecie().then(function(data) {
        yyy = "akkhhh";
    });

  var json = JSON.stringify({
    anObject: ttt, 
    anArray: yyy, 
  });
  res.end(json);

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Promises are asynchronous, so `ttt` and `yyy` haven't yet been assigned when you create the `json` object for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in asynchronous nature of `Promise.then`. You see, `JSON.stringify` and `res.end` is called before both of the promises will be resolved. To send the response only when all the data are fetched you have to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method.

Here is an example of how it could be done:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    var promises = [];

    promises.push(database.getTagType().then(function(data){
        return "pfff";
    }));

    promises.push(database.getSpecie().then(function(data) {
        return "akkhhh";
    }));

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
        // Actually, express can stringify response for us. Also it adds
        // correct "Content-Type" header.
        res.json({
            anObject: values[0], 
            anArray: values[1]
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Something went wrong. Let the error middleware deal with the problem.
        next(error);
        // Instead we can just send an error response, like so:
        // res.status(500).json({error: error.toString()});
    });
});
```

Comment: Add `catch` block, because with your current code, the user will never receive a response if any error will be raised.

Comment: You're right, thank you for the notice. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The database calls are asynchronous. They are returning promises and you are appending the `then` functions, but the way javascript runs, the function is calling `getTagType` and `getSpecie` and then sending the response with `res.end()` *before* the promises resolve and the db call is over.

You need to make sure you wait for all the promises to resolve before replying with the response, this essentially calls for nesting the `then()` functions.

Like so:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){

  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});

    var tag = database.getTagType();
    // `tag` is now a promise

    var specie = database.getSpecie();
    // `specie` is a promise

    Promise.all([tag, specie]).then(function(values) {
    // this code is executed once both promises have resolved, the response has come back from the database

        var json = JSON.stringify({
            tag: values[0],
            specie: values[1]
        )};

        res.end(json);
    });
});
```

This function will return immediately, but won't call `res.end()` until the database calls are completed.

This code gets cleaner once `async/await` is added to the language :)

Comment: @user2795508 can you mark an answer as "accepted" so people know it's solved? Should be the check mark next to the answer.